# adb "am start -n" not working for debug version

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to use adb to launch activites for testing,But it does not work for the debug version :

This works

```
adb shell am start -n com.xx.xx/.main.ParentActivity
```

This doesn't

```
adb shell am start -n com.xx.xx.debug/.main.ParentActivity
```

Both debug and release packages are available under /data/data

Answer (score 1):

If you have class `com.xx.xx.main.ParentActivity` and your application id is `com.xx.xx.debug` then you have to specify FQCN like this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.xx.xx.debug/com.xx.xx.main.ParentActivity
```

Dot just after slash is shortcut which can be used only if FQCN starts with application id.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `adb shell am start -D -n com.xx.xx.debug/.main.ParentActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`
2. then you will be able to attach your debugger (via your IDE) and the app will start (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/05/new-in-105-attach-debugger-to-a-running-android-process/)